# Trying to fix missing data on Azure Timeseries Insight

Tags: azure, azure-timeseries-insights

I am trying to insert some missing data on my azure time series inside due to the several microservices failure. So between 20 Nov 2022 5pm to 9pm there were missing data and i had tried to fill those gaps by resubmitting the data that belongs to those period but the it seemed the TSI not updating the changes so i still saw the gap between 5pm and 9pm. My question is : does Azure TSI capable of inserting the missing data or not ?

Answer (score 0):

John, yes. Please double check if you set the timestamp property in your Event Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/time-series-insights/concepts-streaming-ingestion-event-sources#event-source-timestamp

If you did, you can send old data by setting the timestamp accordingly in your payload.